# My default boxplot did not have the color

Tags: python, boxplot

I just want the normal default boxplot pattern.
But my boxplot doesn't have color.
What's the reason?

My plot:
[image]

But expecting something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use seaborn for plotting boxplots.

```
import seaborn as sns

def boxplot(x,y):
   sns.boxplot(x=x,y=y)

boxplot(x=data_on_x-axis,y=data_on_y-axis)
```

I created  a function so that we can create plots every time it's needed without writing everything again.
just passing the columns will work.

Comment: thank you!  `sns.boxplot (data=xx)` really work     but the plot is too colorful

Comment: different colours help in differentiating the plots. if the above solution helped accept it and keep going!!!